# Where can I find tickets from Stockholm to Cape Verde?

Tags: air-travel, flight-search-engines, cape-verde

I'm trying to find tickets from Stockholm/Arlanda to any of the Cape Verde islands, nothing shows up in the search engines.

Can I find a list of airlines that frequent those routes or are there any more in-depth search-engines?

There are plenty of charter flights going.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia is actually quite useful for that. It has a [list of airports in the country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_Cape_Verde). I can easily find flights to some of them on the usual search engines, mostly with TAP through Lisbon. [TACV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TACV), the flag carrier, also appears to offer many flights.

If you want to do a “broad search”, without specifying an airport, you can also use [rome2rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/en/s/Stockholm/Cape-Verde), [Skyscanner](http://www.skyscanner.com) or [Adioso](http://www.adioso.com). All three accept a country name as destination and the first one even searches other modes of transportation and some charter/low-cost carriers.

If you don't find what you want through the search engines, you can also check the airport pages on Wikipedia. There is an article about most of them, typically with a mostly up-to-date list of destinations and carriers. Thus, you can for example easily find out that TUIFlyNordic offers flights to [Aristides Pereira International Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aristides_Pereira_International_Airport) from Arlanda (apparently sold through [Fritidsresor.se](http://www.fritidsresor.se/)).

Comment: This is great. I also found that several of the charter-companies sell seats in their air-planes without all the rest of the stuff for reasonable prices.

Comment: Google flights too!

Answer (score 0):

[Flightconnections.com](https://www.flightconnections.com) is also quite useful for this purpose.  In particular, it is easy to find and determine the better-connected airports in a country (they're color-coded by the number destinations served).  Clicking on the destinations will then show the airline(s) that serve that route.  It also shows the days of the week on which these flights occur;  more conventional search engines will often require you to specify a day for the flight, and if you pick the wrong day of the week the options won't show up.

Their information is not always 100% accurate, but it's a good place to start.  Currently, a lot of the links shown are with TUI Fly;  I suspect that these are seasonal flights for vacationers.